# Google forms- export PDF draft and electronic signature

Tags: google-apps-script

Good morning everyone!  This is a 2-part Google forms question.

1) Is it possible for someone to fill out a Google form and send a "draft" version of their responses to a third party before hitting Submit?

2) Is there a way to allow for electronic signatures within Google Forms?

Answer (score 0):

An unfortunate 'No' to both questions (though you might be able to use the file upload feature to upload an image as a signature; no way to verify that it is a signature though). If you want that kind of functionality in a GSuite context, you can deploy a Google Apps Script Web App that leverages standard HTML, CSS and Javascript.

You can also integrate the GSuite platform (via Apps Script) with 3rd party form apps (for example: TypeForm) using REST APIs, so you're not without options.